# How do I prevent a massive SELECT from blocking other statements?

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure-sql-database, blocking, query-performance

Our SQL Azure database contains a massive `SELECT` statement that runs something like once per day. The heavy `SELECT` statement contains no locking hints. Recently we observed some stalls in production and here's what `sys.dm_exec_requests` was showing for that period of time... The longest running query was that heavy `SELECT` which had `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait type. Next were other queries - most often `INSERT` statements which had `PAGEIOLATCH_EX` wait type, all running for dozens of seconds instead of completing promptly. So basically that heavy `SELECT` alone disrupts other queries.

How do I resolve this? I'm okay with heavy `SELECT` running slowly but other queries should not be disrupted.

Comment: It seems to be possible to run the select under a user with different priority http://stackoverflow.com/a/65439 but no idea if it would help in your case.

Comment: What does your execution plan look like? There may be ways that the query can be improved to reduce IO and therefore reduce blocking.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson I cannot even obtain an execution plan anymore because that requires running the query and disrupting production.

Comment: Can you not backup to a test server and run it there?

Comment: @MarkSinkinson I guess I can but that surely requires quite a lot of effort and time.

Comment: Execution plan should be available without "running" the query.

Comment: @jkavalik That would be a speculation, not a real plan.

Comment: @sharptooth Afaik the optimizer uses that speculation to plan the query execution, the "real" plan is more exact, but seems actually a bit useless as it works only in hindsight.

Comment: Is it possible to even just post an anonymized version of the query? Your only two real options here are to either speed up the query or look at different isolation levels as Paul mentions in his answer. You could also run sp_WhoIsActive and see what plan it is currently using.

Comment: @MarkWilkinson Well, nothing interesting, just a heavy `SELECT` which was likely causing either a table scan or gazillion of index seeks. The problem was resolved by creating a suitable index. Looks like something is seriously wrong with SQL Azure performance tiers.

Answer (score 8):

Your main options are:

1. Tune the `SELECT` query so it uses fewer I/O resources.
2. Run the query at a quiet time.
3. Run the query on a separate copy of the database (e.g. a readable secondary).
4. Run the query in an I/O-limited resource pool [as described here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2013/11/07/io-resource-governance-in-sql-server-2014.aspx)*.
5. Move to a size/tier with higher I/O capacity.

Side note: This answer does not mention using isolation levels like [RCSI](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation) or SI. Those apply to *lock blocking*, and the question contains no reference to that: `PAGEIOLATCH_XX` waits are associated with waits on *physical I/O*.

---

*This feature may not be available in Azure SQL Database.